# Is it possible to inject bean in request scope if possible and if it is not active for thread, then inject prototype?

Tags: java, spring

I want to inject request scoped bean into singleton scoped. I can do it using `Provider`. The problem occurs when no scope `request` is not active for a thread. In such case I would like to inject bean in e.g. `prototype` scope. Is that possible?
E.g. code:

```
public class Tenant {

    private String name;

    ...
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

  @Bean
  @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_REQUEST)
  public Tenant prototypeBean() {
      return new Tenant();
  }

  @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
  public Tenant prototypeBean() {
      return new Tenant();
  }

  @Bean
  public MySingletonBean singletonBean() {
      return new MySingletonBean();
  }
```

```
public class MySingletonBean {

  @Autowired
  private Provider<Tenant> beanProvider;
//inject conditionally on request or prototype scope

  public void showMessage() {
      Tenant bean = beanProvider.get();
  }
}
```

I want to avoid error with this message:

```
Error creating bean with name 'tenantDetails': 
Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; 
consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to 
refer to it from a singleton; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound 
request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an 
actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally 
receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request 
and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside 
of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use 
RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current 
request.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something like this is required, then the design of an application should be reconsidered.

Is it possible? Yes.

```
@Component
@RequestScope
public class RequestScopeTenant implements Tenant {

    private String name;

    ...
}
```

This way we have request scoped bean.

```
@Component
@PrototypeScope
public class DefaultTenant implements Tenant {

    private String name;

    ...
}
```

here we have our default Tenant.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

  @Primary
  @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
  public Tenant prototypeBean(RequestScopeTenant requestScopeTenant, DefaultTenant defaultTenant) {
      return RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null ? requestScopeTenant : defaultTenant;
  }

  @Bean
  public MySingletonBean singletonBean() {
      return new MySingletonBean();
  }
```

This way when no request scope is available default tenant is returned.

And again, if you would have to implement something like this - change the design or create custom scope.